# How to dispatch a request depending on an exception?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a HTTP servlet that should redirect a user to a page depending on whether an object could be initialized properly or not.
Consider the following example:

```java
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    SomeClass sc;

        try {
            sc = new SomeClass(request);
        } catch (SomeClassSomeException e) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Ex1.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (SomeClassAnotherException e) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Ex2.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Success.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Is this the recommended way of doing this? Would another way of handling this be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the recommended way of doing this?

It should work (modulo the issue below).  In some contexts I would do it this way.

> Would another way of handling this be more appropriate?

In other contexts (e.g. if I had lots of servlets which needed the same dispatching logic) I might do the dispatching of exceptions in a filter, or some other way.

---

There is one issue that you need to beware of.  If the request processing has already "committed" the response before the exception is thrown, then forwarding to a JSP (or anything else) could be problematic.  However, it looks like that can't happen ... given your current code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
SomeClass sc;

    try {
        sc = new SomeClass(request);
    } catch (SomeClassSomeException e) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Ex1.jsp?error="+e).forward(request, response);
    } catch (SomeClassAnotherException e) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Ex1.jsp?error="+e").forward(request, response);
    }

request.getRequestDispatcher("/Success.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

}

On Ex1.jsp, you can use

```
<%= request.getParameter("error")%>
```

It will retireive the error message on the Ex1.jsp page.So a single page can handle all the error messages.

Hope this gives you a better approach to your solution.